# How do I validate form elements via onblur events?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to validate a form element when it loses focus. But I am having issues calling the validation script.
I have tried both:

```
drupal_add_js('(
    function ($)
        {
        $("#edit-field-organization-url").blur(
            function()
                {
                //alert(\'jQuery Exec!\');
                $(this).validate();
                }
        );
        }(jQuery));', 'inline');
```

and

```
$form['field_organization_url']=array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Website URL'),
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#value' => 'www.google.com',
    '#description' => t('Enter website URL.'),
    '#element_validate' => array('hook_node_validate'),
    '#attributes' => array(
        //'onblur'=> '$(this).validate();'),
        //'onblur'=> 'alert(\'jQuery Exec!\');')
    '#required' => TRUE
    );
```

but neither work. I'm guessing this isnt the proper drupal way to call the validation functions.

#########################

UPDATE

#########################

I still cant seem to get it working. The validation code now runs every time the page is loaded and doesnt seem to be tide to the onblur event even though I have it set in the clientside_ validation module:

> file - template.php:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
switch ($form_id) {
case 'custom_content_type_node_form':
$form['custom_content_type_node_form']=array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Website URL'),
'#value' => 'http://www.google.com',
'#description' => t('Enter website URL.'),
'#element_validate' => array('hook_clientside_validate_url'),
'#required' => TRUE);`

file - custom.module:
`function hook_clientside_validation_rule_alter(&$js_rules, $element, $context) {
switch($context['type']) {
case 'element_validate':
if (in_array('hook_clientside_validate_url', $context['functions'])) {
hook_clientside_validate_url($js_rules, $element);
}
function hook_clientside_validate_url($js_rules, $element) {
//validation code here
}`
```

Comment: Your JS has a syntax error - the last line should be `})(jQuery);`

Comment: Thx, but even when thats fixed... in both methods the alert box pops up but the validate function does not fire. i have a feeling simply calling a jquery validation is not tied to drupal's php based validation... but i was hoping since they are both tied to the form itself it could still work. :/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - which JS library are you using for validation? Ie what is making that `validate()` method available to you? Instinct would say it's the standard jQuery validate plugin but you haven't mentioned...whichever plugin you're using, how have you integrated it with the form API? Have you used a contrib module or written something custom?

Comment: ohh, i see, validate() is not a core jquery method. I didnt realize this, so to answer your question I am not using any plugins. I have a php validation function in hook_node_validate but it validates the whole form onsubmit. I would like to validate certain fields as soon as they lose focus.

Comment: Gotcha, there's nothing like that built in but it's easy enough to get. I've put an answer in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal doesn't have any client-side validation by default, but you can get that functionality with the [Clientside Validation](https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module:

> This module adds clientside validation (aka "Ajax form validation") for all forms and webforms using jquery.validate.

According to [the docs](https://drupal.org/node/1324924) it has a "Validate on blur" option, so it should be just what you're looking for.